# client server application and sharead database

Tags: database, client-server, database-migration, concept

I have an application_version1.0.0. To run this application (version 1.0.0) it should be connect to database (the schema of database have a version db_v1.0.0).

I added some feature for my application (I changed some table, I removed other table, ..).
Now, my application have a version 1.0.1 and my database have a version 1.0.1.

I need when I have the application version 1.0.1 it can connect to the database with version 1.0.0 and my application will run correctly. Don’t forget in my application I have some request to the database:

Example:

```
Database_version_1.0.0: the customer table have this fields (id, name);
Application_version_1.0.0: getPIDCustomer () {select name from customer ;}
```

Now:

```
Database_version_1.0.1: the customer table have this fields  (id, PID, name).
Application_version_1.0.1: getPIDCustomer () {select name, pid from customer ;}
```

In this application I can open the older version database version 1.0.0

How can modify this to allow my application_version_1.0.1 to work with database_version_1.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in the past.

Step 1: your database version must be... in database. I eman, a table wit a row.
Step 2: once you run the application read db version. Every single time you have difference in data in the different db version, you must handle it via code. It requires a lot of effort.

There are more elegan way, but not always applicable. It depend from the nature of your application.
One is to have functions or view to retrive data.
For example, in your getPIDCustomer() you can

```
select * from viewpidcustomer
```

In different db version you have more or less columns.
You must hande your code to see if a column is present or not and assign default values or raise error if not possible.